# Python- evaluate a contour for a given number

Tags: python

So I have a Dataset that I have created a contour for. E.g.

```
    cs=m.contourf(x,y,z)
```

I also have point data that I want to plot, with the same colors as used in the contour. I know how to get the cmap object and list of levels for the contour, but I am unsure how to relate the cmap to the levels.

Ideally, I would like to receive an array like

```
['#00e400','#ffff00','#ff7e00','#ff0000','#99004c','#7e0023']
```

however, I can work with other codes for colors. I have a routine that evaluates the point data if it is between levels, and returns the corresponding color in the array, but for it to work, I would need an array of colors. Any ideas on how to go about this?

**Edit**

Example:

[image: Example]

Note the point data within overtop the contours. There are values associated with each of the points. The colors of those circles correspond to the color associated with the value at that point.

I would like to replicate this. With this image, I supplied a list of colors; for my next image, I desire not to supply the colors.

Comment: You should show more code, as it is easier to understand what you have and what do you want. Actually, it is very difficult to get which libraries are you using (I suppose matplotlib), and what is _m_ in your example

Comment: I clarfied it. I am using matplotlib, numpy, basemap, mpl_toolkits and a couple other irrelevant modules like netCDF4, os, sys, etc.